Create elasticache cluster from snapshot
I have an Elasticache cluster and a snapshot (rdb file) on S3, the bucket and also elasticache are deployed using terraform code.
but it fails everytime with this error :

Download of snapshot arn:aws:s3:::bucket-test/raw-data/dump.rdb failed for node 0001. Failed to retrieve file from S3

Here is the code used to grant access on S3 bucket :

module "bucket" {
  source                = "tfr_repo/data/s3-intelligent-tiering-bucket/aws"

  context               = var.context
  product               = var.product.name
  use_default_lifecycle = false
  tags                  = var.tags
 
  bucket_owner          = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  public_restrictions   = {
    block_public_acls       = false
    block_public_policy     = false
    ignore_public_acls      = false
    restrict_public_buckets = false
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access_from_another_account" {
  bucket = module.bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_access_from_another_account.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_access_from_another_account" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "CanonicalUser"
      identifiers = ["540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      module.bucket.arn,
      "${module.bucket.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}

Taking a look at the file's permissions on S3 :

Any ideas what could've be missing ?

Can you try something like "${module.bucket.arn}/raw-data/*"?

I tried it, but it didn't work, same error :/

Which region are you in?

I'm in eu-west-1

Cool, I'm looking in the docs, thanks. Would "${module.bucket.arn}/raw-data/dump.rdb" work?

Unfortunately, even this "${module.bucket.arn}/raw-data/dump.rdb" didn't work

Is the object prefix the same in the question as in the bucket then?

Yes it is the same, i made sure of it, I added the module conf (if it may give you any idea), thank you so much for your help

And what would happen if instead of the canonical user you try with:             principals = { type = "Service", identifiers = ["eu-west-1.elasticache-snapshot.amazonaws.com"] }? And allow the bucket and object access with module.bucket.arn and "${module.bucket.arn}/raw-data/dump.rdb"?

So actually the problem was related to KMS, I just removed the encryption applied to the file, retried, and it worked, so probably I will have to add kms encrypt, decrypt to the policy, thank you for the help
